# Xml views acting like text

Tags: android, xml, button

How can i make multiple Views (ex. Buttons) line up like text. If the width goes over the maximum width of the device, the View is moved down. Just like the text in this question.

Fyi, all views have the same height but different width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout). It will probably satisfy your condition. I had the same requirement too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GridView` and button as grid view item.

Comment: Won't that make the buttons position permanent? Becuase if one is deleted, i want the next item to take its place.

Comment: just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() when you remove the button